# Footable doSort not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable, columnsorting

I'm using [footable](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable) version 2.0.3.

When I'm trying to sort manually with...

```
$('.footable').data('footable-sort').doSort(4, true)
```

... I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
    at Sort.p.doSort (http://localhost:8080/js/footable.sort.js:125:23)
```

It's very strange. For example, filter is working `$('.footable').data('footable-filter').filter('some text')`, this means there is no problem with my table.

Inspecting the footable code, `ft.columns` is empty, so `column` is undefined

```
  var $table = $(ft.table),
        $tbody = $table.find('> tbody'),
        column = ft.columns[columnIndex],
        $th = $table.find('> thead > tr:last-child > th:eq(' + columnIndex + ')'),
        cls = ft.options.classes.sort,
        evt = ft.options.events.sort;
```

Comment: Can you provide your html for table? Do you have data-sort-initial attribute on one of th?

Comment: Hi, if were in footable v3, anyone knows how to code it similar to do doSort? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when footable is called twice. Reproduced [here in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbxs84Lu/21/).

`$('.footable').footable();`